# Get additional column using functional select

Tags: kdb, k

How to get an additional column of type `string` using `?`?

I tried this:

```
t:([]c1:`a`b`c;c2:1 2 3)
?[t;();0b;`c1`c2`c3!(`c1;`c2;10)]           / ok
?[t;();0b;`c1`c2`c3!(`c1;`c2;enlist(`abc))] / ok
?[t;();0b;`c1`c2`c3!(`c1;`c2;"10")]         / 'length
?[t;();0b;`c1`c2`c3!(`c1;`c2;enlist("10"))] / 'length
```

but got `'length` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first case works because an atom will automatically expand to the required length. For a compound column you'll need to explicitly generate the correct length as follows

```
q)select c1,c2,c3:`abc,c4:10,c5:count[i]#enlist"abc" from t
c1 c2 c3  c4 c5
------------------
a  1  abc 10 "abc"
b  2  abc 10 "abc"
c  3  abc 10 "abc"

// in functional form
q)?[t;();0b;`c1`c2`c3!(`c1;`c2;(#;(count;`i);(enlist;"abc")))]
c1 c2 c3
-----------
a  1  "abc"
b  2  "abc"
c  3  "abc"
```

Jason

Comment: Thank you Jason! Yes, the same problem I've faced recently even with non-functional select, and your answer helped me twice! :)